# How to perform multiple simultaneous actions in one thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I need ships to load and unload cargo at the same time.
Is there a way to do that in java?

I managed to make multiple ships work in port at the same time, but they first unload cargo and then load new crates.

That is my variant of Ship class

```
public class Ship implements Runnable {
    String name;
    Port port;
    Queue<Goods> storage;
    Pier pier;
    int capacity;
    int numOnBoard;

    public Ship(String name, Port port, int capacity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.port = port;
        storage = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(capacity);
        this.capacity = capacity;
        int num=(int)(Math.random()*capacity);
        numOnBoard=num;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            storage.add(new Goods());
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            int unl = 0;
            int l = 0;
            pier = port.getPier();
            System.out.println("Ship " + name + " taken " + pier.name);
            while (unload()) {
                if(unl>=numOnBoard) break;
                unl++;
                System.out.println("Ship " + name + " unloaded cargo.");
                Thread.sleep(new Random(100).nextInt(500));
            }
            System.out.println("Ship " + name + " unloaded " + unl + " crates.");
            Thread.sleep(100);
            while (load()) {
                l++;
                System.out.println("Ship " + name + " loaded cargo.");
                Thread.sleep(new Random(100).nextInt(500));
            }
            System.out.println("Ship " + name + " loaded " + l + " crates.");
            port.releasePier(pier);
            System.out.println("Ship " + name + " released " + pier.name);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean unload() {
        if (storage.size() <= 0) return false;
        return port.addGoods(storage.poll());
    }

    private boolean load() {
        if (storage.size() >= capacity) return false;
        return port.takeGoods(storage,numOnBoard);
    }
}
```

And the Port

```java
public class Port {
    Queue<Pier> piers;
    Queue<Goods> goods;
    int capacity;

    public Port(int pierCount, int capacity) {
        goods = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(capacity);
        piers = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(pierCount);
        this.capacity = capacity;
        for (int i = 0; i < pierCount; i++)
            piers.add(new Pier("Pier " + (i + 1)));
        int num=(int)(Math.random()*capacity);
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            goods.add(new Goods());
        }
    }

    public boolean addGoods(Goods item) {
        if (goods.size() >= capacity) return false;
        return goods.add(item);
    }

    public boolean takeGoods(Queue<Goods> storage, int wasOnBoard) {
        if (goods.size() <= wasOnBoard) return false;
        return storage.add(goods.poll());
    }

    public Pier getPier() {
        Pier taken = piers.poll();
        while (taken == null) {
            try {
                System.out.println("There aren't any free piers. Waiting...");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                taken = piers.poll();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return taken;
    }

    public void releasePier(Pier pier) {
        piers.add(pier);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Port port = new Port(4, 50);
        ArrayList<Thread> ships = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            ships.add(new Thread(new Ship("ship " + (i+1), port, 30)));
        }
        for (Thread t : ships)
            t.start();
    }
}
```

I need each ship to load and unload cargo at the same time

Comment: One thread can do one thing at the time. So answer is no. You can't execute two pieces of code in same thread simultaneously.

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of threads – to execute things simultaneously?

Comment: @PSharuba this is the point of multiple threads, not single thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish within a single thread is exactly what multiple threads are for. Multi-threading enables you to write in a way where multiple activities can proceed concurrently in the same program:

> A multi-threaded program contains two or more parts that can run concurrently and each part can handle a different task at the same time making optimal use of the available resources specially when your computer has multiple CPUs.
>
> By definition, multitasking is when multiple processes share common
>   processing resources such as a CPU. Multi-threading extends the idea
>   of multitasking into applications where you can subdivide specific
>   operations within a single application into individual threads. Each
>   of the threads can run in parallel. The OS divides processing time not
>   only among different applications, but also among each thread within
>   an application.

Read more about Java multi-threading [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm).